# expanding an ID key from different columns and between specific years

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
    begyr1 gvkey1 endyr1 pdpco2 begyr2 gvkey2 endyr2 pdpco3 begyr3 gvkey3 endyr3 pdpco4 begyr4 gvkey4 endyr4
    1982  10537   1999     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1995  63658   1999     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1961   9236   1996     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1990 101352   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1963   8150   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1961   9967   1988     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1973   5578   2004     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1959   7946   1991     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
    1989  24467   1995     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1994  62471   2002     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1965   8783   1995  29217   1996  29217   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1954   4521   1983  14572   1987  14572   1987     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1966   2919   1988   9411   1989   9411   1995     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1969   6785   1996   7985   1997   7985   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1995  65578   2004   5180   2005   5180   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1985  11904   1998  10787   1999  10787   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1961   9967   1988   2403   1989   2403   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1981   8658   1999   3336   2000   3336   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1950   6096   1999  10787   2000  10787   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
   1980   2901   1990   3011   1991   3011   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

The columns:

`begyr[x]` = beginning year

`gvkey[x]` = ID key

`endyr[x]` = end year

So, row `11` in the data would look like:

Row:

```
begyr1 gvkey1 endyr1 pdpco2 begyr2 gvkey2 endyr2 
1965   8783   1995  29217   1996  29217   2005

1965   8783  29217 
1966   8783  29217
1967   8783  29217
1968   8783  29217
...
1993   8783  29217
1994   8783  29217
1995   8783  29217
...
1996   29217 29217
1997   29217 29217
1998   29217 29217
...
2004   29217 29217
2005   29217 29217
```

I have been following a document in which they provide STATA code to handle this part of the process. From what I am understanding from it the authors define a `gvkey` as NULL and then construct a simple forloop across the columns.

```
gen gvkey=.
forvalue i=1/5 {
replace gvkey = gvkey`i' if gvkey`i'~=. & year>=begyr`i' &
year<=endyr`i'
}
keep if gvkey~=.
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(begyr1 = c(1982L, 1995L, 1961L, 1990L, 1963L, 
1961L, 1973L, 1959L, 1989L, 1994L, 1965L, 1954L, 1966L, 1969L, 
1995L, 1985L, 1961L, 1981L, 1950L, 1980L, NA, 1950L, NA, 1950L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1950L, 1975L, 1960L, 1991L, 1961L, 1977L, 
1977L, 1995L, 1977L, 1991L, 1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 1960L, 1968L, 
1950L, 1968L, 1986L, 1950L, 1950L, NA, 1984L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey1 = c(10537L, 63658L, 9236L, 101352L, 8150L, 
9967L, 5578L, 7946L, 24467L, 62471L, 8783L, 4521L, 2919L, 6785L, 
65578L, 11904L, 9967L, 8658L, 6096L, 2901L, NA, 3650L, NA, 1300L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5245L, 9844L, 3167L, 25723L, 10633L, 
10329L, 10329L, 66034L, 9226L, 25723L, 2827L, 2827L, 2827L, 7686L, 
8829L, 2827L, 8829L, 13571L, 2827L, 7099L, NA, 11907L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), endyr1 = c(1999L, 1999L, 1996L, 2006L, 
2005L, 1988L, 2004L, 1991L, 1995L, 2002L, 1995L, 1983L, 1988L, 
1996L, 2004L, 1998L, 1988L, 1999L, 1999L, 1990L, NA, 2006L, NA, 
2006L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1987L, 1980L, 1988L, 1997L, 1986L, 
1996L, 1996L, 2000L, 1983L, 1997L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1981L, 
1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1987L, 1985L, 1995L, NA, 2006L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pdpco2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 29217L, 14572L, 9411L, 7985L, 5180L, 10787L, 2403L, 
3336L, 10787L, 3011L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
61132L, 2146L, 24969L, 4140L, 14641L, 3282L, 3282L, 10530L, 6066L, 
4140L, 162254L, 162254L, 162254L, 28478L, 13333L, 162254L, 13333L, 
4781L, 162254L, 100528L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), begyr2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1996L, 
1987L, 1989L, 1997L, 2005L, 1999L, 1989L, 2000L, 2000L, 1991L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1995L, 1981L, 1991L, 
1998L, 1988L, 1997L, 1997L, 2002L, 1984L, 1998L, 1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1983L, 1986L, 1987L, 1986L, 1988L, 1987L, 1997L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29217L, 14572L, 9411L, 7985L, 5180L, 10787L, 
2403L, 3336L, 10787L, 3011L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 61132L, 2145L, 24969L, 4140L, 14641L, 3282L, 3282L, 10530L, 
6066L, 4140L, 13934L, 13934L, 13934L, 5555L, 13333L, 13934L, 
13333L, 4781L, 13934L, 100528L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), endyr2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005L, 
1987L, 1995L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1998L, 1983L, 1997L, 
2003L, 1988L, 2001L, 2001L, 2003L, 1993L, 2003L, 1996L, 1996L, 
1996L, 1991L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1990L, 1996L, 1998L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pdpco3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13197L, 2146L, 1278L, 29685L, 
4735L, 5606L, 5606L, 7883L, 19349L, 29685L, 162254L, 162254L, 
162254L, 28478L, 6096L, 162254L, 6096L, 3586L, 162254L, 157415L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), begyr3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1999L, 1984L, 1998L, 
2004L, 1989L, 2002L, 2002L, 2004L, 1994L, 2004L, 1998L, 1998L, 
1998L, 1992L, 1997L, 1998L, 1997L, 1991L, 1998L, 2000L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13197L, 2146L, 1278L, 29685L, 
4735L, 5606L, 5606L, 7883L, 19349L, 29685L, 125434L, 125434L, 
125434L, 28478L, 6096L, 125434L, 6096L, 3586L, 125434L, 148971L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), endyr3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1999L, 2005L, 1999L, 
2004L, 2003L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2004L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 1997L, 1999L, 2002L, 1999L, 1995L, 2002L, 2000L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pdpco4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 162254L, 162254L, 162254L, 14385L, 10787L, 162254L, 
10787L, 12679L, 162254L, 157415L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), begyr4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 1998L, 2000L, 2003L, 2000L, 1996L, 2003L, 2001L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 162254L, 162254L, 162254L, 14385L, 10787L, 
162254L, 10787L, 12679L, 162254L, 157415L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), endyr4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2005L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach to your problem may look like this. First, convert the dataset to tidy data. Second, filter the dataset. As `year` was not given, I used `year <- 1990` as an example. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# convert to tidy data
data_tidy <- data %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(begyr1:endyr4) %>% 
  extract(name, into = c("var", "idx"), regex = "([a-z]+)(\\d{1})$") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("id", "idx"), names_from = "var", values_from = "value")
# filter data
year <- 1990

data_long %>% 
  filter(!is.na(gvkey), year >= begyr, year <= endyr)

# A tibble: 33 x 6
      id idx   begyr  gvkey endyr pdpco
   <int> <chr> <int>  <int> <int> <int>
 1     1 1      1982  10537  1999    NA
 2     3 1      1961   9236  1996    NA
 3     4 1      1990 101352  2006    NA
 4     5 1      1963   8150  2005    NA
 5     7 1      1973   5578  2004    NA
 6     8 1      1959   7946  1991    NA
 7     9 1      1989  24467  1995    NA
 8    11 1      1965   8783  1995    NA
 9    13 2      1989   9411  1995  9411
10    14 1      1969   6785  1996    NA
# ... with 23 more rows
```